# where is the faulty logic in this re-heap function?

Tags: c++, heap, deque

I'm currently working with a heap structure which is suppose to be used to sort numbers in an array. I have done something like this in the code when I want to sort the structure when I pop(dequeue) a element from the heap.

```
template<typename T>
inline void dHeap<T>::reHeapDown(int root, int bottom)
{
    int minChild;
    int rightChild;
    int leftChild;
    int temp;



// Get index of root's right/left child
leftChild = root * 2 + 1;
rightChild = root * 2 + 2;

//Then we are not done with re-heaping
if (leftChild <= bottom)
{
    if (leftChild == bottom)
    {
        minChild = leftChild;
    }

    else
    {
        if (arr[leftChild] <= arr[rightChild])
            minChild = leftChild;
        else
            minChild = rightChild;
    }

    if (arr[root] > arr[minChild])
    {
        // Swap these two elements
        temp = arr[root];
        arr[root] = arr[minChild];
        arr[minChild] = temp;
        // Make recursive call till reheaping completed
        reHeapDown(minChild, bottom);
    }
}
}
```

My thought here is that the lowest value in the heap always will be in the root and that's the value that I will be poped(dequeued) in my pop function.
But I'm having some problem that it wont sort the heap correctly. 
is there something wrong with my logic in this function and if so, where is it?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Your code is correct. A min heap is not guaranteed to be balanced or sorted. All you can assume is the root element is the minimum and every parent is lesser than its children. If you want to sort it, you will need to implement a way to sort it...

Comment: @attersson aha okay! I didn't know that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922535/heapsort-algorithm-using-min-heap?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

Building a heap only enforces the property:

- in case of min heap every parent is lesser than it children
- in case of max heap every parent is greater than its children.
- in case of min-max heap even depth levels (0,2,4..) are lesserr and odd levels (1,3,5...) are greater than their respective children.

However the heap will not necessarily be sorted. It will be balanced, because it is filled in order, level by level, from left to right.

[Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) will sort an array by using heap functions. The final array will also work as a balanced and sorted heap.

Comment: Actually, a binary heap also guarantees the shape property: every level, except possibly the last, is fully filled. If the last level is not full, then it's filled from the left. As such, this *is* a balanced tree.